# worksheet_calculate() is not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have added a private sub worksheet_calculate() in a sheet called Main. I have a value in column AP with formulas derived from other sheets and if that number is greater than value in X I want to display a message as a warning that it's over, but the code is not working any suggestions why?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Sheets("Main").Range("AP7").value > Sheets("Main").Range("x7").value Then
    MsgBox "You Are Over Pieces Suggested"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it get called on Calculate Sheet, clicking the button?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav what button are you referring to?

Comment: So, In your main macro, how do you call this macro? also if it is being called correctly, try Range("x1").value, just incase it isn't being recognised as one!

Comment: The above code works fine for me. Yet, you might want to check the following three: (1) `Range("x1")` is not precise. You might want to change that to `Sheet("Main").Range("x1").Value` (2) Did you place the code on the correct sheet? (3) Are you sure you picked the correct event? If `Application.Calculation` is set to manual or something is changed which does not require calculation then this event does not fire: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301178.aspx

Comment: the Calc Sheet button, Shift F9, on the sheet this code is under.

Comment: @Ralph I have changed that in my edited post,I have placed it in the correct sheet called main, however I have other private subs worksheet_change, but I don't think these events are a problem. And lastly this event is the only one I thought of that will generate a message if a cell is greater than another cell display a message. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is Options>Formula>workbook calculation set to automatic??

Comment: Are events enabled? Check `?application.EnableEvents` in the immediate window of the VBE.

Comment: @Ralph I would presume so because all other events are triggered accordingly except this one

Comment: One last suggestion: change the first line to `If CDbl(Sheets("Main").Range("AP1").Value) > CDbl(Sheets("Main").Range("x1").Value) Then` and then force a calculation by entering into an empty cell `=1+1` (or some other formula).

Comment: @Luis What is the actual contents of `AP7` and `X7`?

Comment: Your original code definitely has to work unless you have disabled automatic formula calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Range("AP7").Value > Range("X7").Value Then
MsgBox "You Are Over Pieces Suggested."
End If
End Sub
```

EDITED####
Edited the original code to run as a Worksheet_Calculate rather than a Change.
Working on trying to set the ranges to columns for you now.

EDIT#########

I flippin love a challenge. Try This.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Set Target = Range("AP:AP").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each c In Target
        If c > Range("X" & c.Row) Then
            MsgBox "You Are Over Pieces Suggested - Cell " & "AP" & c.Row
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added that onto my "Main" Sheet and still nothing. AP value is 4224 derived from a formula that includes other sheet value in X is 2526 derived from formula only from the sheet "main" any other suggestions as in why? Could it be that I have mutliple events in the "Main sheet"?

Comment: try removing the `Sheets("Main").` part from it for starters. Forgot to remove that in my code. not needed if the code is being put in the "Main" sheet anyway. if you have multiple `Worksheet_Calculate()` subs, then yes. that would be an issue.

Comment: as a note I do have multiple worksheet_change events

Comment: perfect so I got it to work, now how a reference the whole columns for "AP" and "X"?

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event would fire only if any cell in the parent sheet **_is edited_** (even canceled). It wouldn't fire if any cell in the parent sheet would change as a result of a calculation. given that and all what you explained, it's hard to believe it would be the solution for your case. On the contrary, the most probable (if not the only possible) cause of your issue is the deactivation of manual calculation option

Comment: Take a look at my edit. i believe it "Should" solve your issue and give you the whole range. Added a reference to the Cell that is over into the message box as you are working with a range. However... If multiple cells are over, this will result in multiple message boxes. one for each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Data Validation on cell AP7 using a "Custom" formula of:  =AP7<=$X$7
Fill in the Error Alert tab on the validation menu: Stop; "You Are Over Pieces Suggested".  I think this might achieve what you want without any macros. In fact, it can prevent an invalid number from being entered in the first place.

Comment: great suggestion except the data validation won't allow you to go over. I just want a warning signal in case the number goes over, but would still allow me to go over